# How to get server local drive path in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

This is the code for c#.

```
 protected string vault = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DocumentVault"];
```

The above code is use to get drive c path at server.
So how can i get the drive c path in vb.net?

Comment: That is getting a key from the web.config file - So, do you want to get a key from the web.config? Or a path from the location of the web app?

Comment: @RenarkLima, I want to get a path from the location of the web app.But how to do it in vb.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verbatim translation for that code into VB.NET is:

```
protected vault As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("DocumentVault")
```

And in your web.config you'll need a corresponding key:

```
<configuration>
       ....
     <appSettings>
       <add key="DocumentVault" value="C:\SomePath\SomeWhere\Else\"/>
     </appSettings>
    ....
</configuration>
```

---

But as per you comment:

> "I want to get a path from the location of the web app.But how to do it in vb.net?"

You'll need to map the path of the root of the app:

```
protected vault As String = Server.MapPath("~\")
Trace.Write(vault) ' <-- Should return the physical root path of the web application
```

Comment: Is it same if i put the appSettings in the winForm App.config?But I tried already, it doesn't access the drive C.

Comment: @user2562841 It should be the same in the App.Config - Are you getting a value returned? With a message box or label write out `vault` and see what you're getting. If you are getting the value you expect, but there's no permissions, that's a different problem, and the account that the app / iis is running under will need the correct permissions to the drive / folder.

Comment: I use messagebox.show can get the path.but when I use it to copy file to tat path.Is not working. No folder is create at that path. Or how to check the permissions?

Comment: So the code is working, you have the path - The application simply doesn't have permissions to write to the path. If you right click the directory, select properties and then security, make sure the user account the application runs under has "modify" access. You'll need to create sub folders separately as well. You can test this by logging into the server / machine with that account and try and create a text document.

Comment: Also, make sure that you've not missed a slash, so `C:\SomePath\SomeFile.ext` hasn't become `C:\SomePathSomeFile.ext`

Comment: I used the <appSettings> code and place ip address at value="\\10.100.100.10\C$\SomePath\SomeWhere\Else\"/> but it show me could not find a part of the path..

Comment: Can you browse to that path? Or can the account the app runs under browse there? A UNC should be fine to use, however the share C$ is usually limited to Administrator accounts as it gives full access to the machine's C drive. Perhaps try and create a share on "SomePath" or "SomeWhere" and map to that. In a nutshell, your code is correct and working as expected. Now it's logical access rights, so falls into the remit of Network Admin. Best bet, login with the same credentials as the app, and see if you can get to the path above.

Comment: I try check the file that located at desktop also can't had error could not find a part of the path.

Comment: If I could I give you more votes because of the effort. And @user2562841, consider creating a new question with your new problems you are facing .

Comment: Thanks @SysDragon - Agreed that @ user2562841 needs a new question really - And his last comment means that he needs to really check the logical permissions!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
vault = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("DocumentVault")
```